# Play Audio File Stored in AWS S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, flutter, amazon-s3, audio-streaming

I have successfully uploaded some audio files via Nodejs to AWS, the file url is also returned from my function. I plan to save this url in MongoDB Atlas as a reference to the original file but before doing that, I tried to play the file (from the url) in my mobile app and it won't play.

The file is in `.m4a` format. How do I get this to work in any audio player for mobile and web? I'm using flutter for  both. I don't want to do `piping, chunking and streaming` manually as this is just a dummy test of the system. The original files to be used in the app will be much larger.

Here's the file url `https://empty-bouquet.s3.af-south-1.amazonaws.com/Dax+-Dear+God.m4a`.
Thanks

Comment: if your bucket file is private then you can't play the file from the URL.

Comment: Thanks, I have fixed that issue from the app side, not server side. I do have a question though, like how do I stream continuous playback from an s3 bucket, like an online radio? Thanks

Comment: did you manage to do forward and backward on the file?

Comment: Yes, seeking you mean?

Comment: Yes when its private, if you did can you share?

Comment: I dont understand what you want me to do here

Answer (score 0):

`.m4a` audios aren't natively streamed from S3, but after a test I can verify that `.mp3` files are. Most browsers will recognize that filetype and render a built-in player for you.

You can convert from one format to another using a lot of free tools. I used Audacity.

And yes, you need to make at least the file public. Or if you're going to do this a lot I would recommend making a bucket policy that makes everything public, no matter what you throw in there.